# If statement based on array list

Tags: javascript

I have an array of urls links:

```
const urlLinks = [`http://1`,
`http:/2`,
`http://3`,
`http://4`,
`http://5`
]
```

How would I write an `if` statement, that would be executed, when at least one of the links in the array is present?

```
if (URL === urlLinks) {
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

`if (urlLinks.includes(URL)) { ... }`

This will return `true` if `URL` is in the `urlLinks` array.

[Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)